# How to normalise dataset for linear/multi regression in python

Tags: python, regression, normalization, linear-regression

I am using a data-set to make some predictions using the multi-variable regression techniques. I have to predict the salary of the employees based on some independent variables like gender, percentage, date of birth, marks in different subjects, degree, specialization etc.

Numeric parameters(eg- marks and percentage in different subjects) are fine to be used with the regression model. But how do we normalize the non-numeric parameters (gender, date of birth, degree, specialization) here ?

P.S. : I am using the [scikit-learn : machine learning in python](http://scikit-learn.org/) package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Normaliz[ing] non-numeric parameters" is actually a huge area of regression. The most common treatment is to turn each categorical into a set of binary variables called [dummy variables](http://www.socialresearchmethods.net/kb/dummyvar.php).

Each categorical with `n` values should be converted into `n-1` dummy variables.  So for example, for gender, you might have one variable, "female", that would be either 0 or 1 at each observation.  Why `n-1` and not `n`?  Because you want to avoid the [dummy variable trap](http://www.algosome.com/articles/dummy-variable-trap-regression.html), where basically the intercept column of all 1's can be reconstructed from a linear combination of your dummy columns. In relatively non-technical terms, that's bad because it messes up the linear algebra needed to do the regression.

I am not so familiar with the scikit-learn library but I urge you to make sure that whatever methods you do use, you ensure that each categorical becomes `n-1` new columns, and not `n`.

Answer (score 1):

You want to encode your categorical parameters.

- For binary categorical parameters such as gender, this is relatively easy: introduce a single binary parameter: 1=female, 0=male.
- If there are more than two categories, you could try the one-hot-encoding.
  Read more on the sci-kit learn documenten:
  http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#encoding-categorical-features

Note that date is not a categorical parameter! Convert it into a unix timestamp (seconds since epoch) and you have a nice parameter on which you can regress.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help you. The whole description of how to use that function is available on this link.

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.normalize.html